# Precise decimal and tax calculation

Tags: contributions, taxes

I have products that cost $10, including a 7% value-added tax. In the price set, I enter 9.345794393 accordingly https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1603, and I include the tax in the contribution type. I thought that CiviCRM had been calculating correctly recently, but it's not doing so anymore. During the initial calculation on dmaster, $20 is correctly displayed, but it's saving as $19.99.

Calculation while typing: [image]

Stored Value : [image]

I am grateful for any hints!

Comment: If you can reproduce on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/, I'd go ahead and call that a bug and report it on https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/-/issues/
If you can work out in which version this problem started, that will be helpful.

Comment: Thank You. Here we go ... https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/-/issues/218